# UISearchController in navigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I'm trying to use the new UISearchController in my tableViewController.

However I'm a bit confused on how it can move up in the navigationController when I press the searchBar like it did with the old searchDisplayController?

At the moment it just stay in the tableHeader.

Here is my code:

```
    self.teamSearchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

        controller.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Minimal
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
       controller.searchBar.showsScopeBar = true
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

        return controller
    })()
```

Controller:

[image]

When I click on searchbar:

[image]

Comment: removing `controller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false` should also give you the behavior you are expecting

Comment: I've added 2 image which descripe the behaviour

Comment: set your searchController's hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation to true and try toggle your ViewController's definesPresentationContext see the result. never hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation to false and never put the search bar on navigationItem's titleView if you want the behavior you mentioning.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can place the `UISearchBar` of `UISearchController` in the navigation bar instead of table header

```
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;

// Include the search bar within the navigation bar.
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchController.searchBar;

self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
```

Comment: I've added 2 image which descripe the behaviour

Comment: Did you try the solution in this answer?

Comment: No but this will add to the top from the beginning and not have the same behaviour as in searchDisplayController

Comment: But i guess its okay if it is in tableHeaderVIew, but then it should be without the cancel button, but if i remove that it gives me the behaviour on the images

Answer (score 4):

`Swift` version:

```
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
self.searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Minimal

// Include the search bar within the navigation bar.
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchController.searchBar
self.definesPresentationContext = true
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the navigation bar.

```
func willPresentSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
}

func willDismissSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false
}
```

If you do this, then you will be able to add it to the table view header AND get the baked-in search controller animation!